# Why does $Resources:wss work in a web control, but $Resources:core does not?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When I have the following in my ascx web control:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:core,Description%>" />
```

I get this error: The resource object with key 'Description' was not found.

But when I change the Literal to:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:wss,viewlsts_desc%>" />
```

The control renders just fine.

What's so special about the wss resource file? How can I use core?

**Update:**

I still don't know why, but it appears that resource files in 14\CONFIG\Resources are available, while files in 14\Resources are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly recommend [SharePoint Resources, Types, Use and Deployment](http://www.mikhaildikov.com/2007/03/sharepoint-resources-types-use-and_2163.html) post which explains differences between SharePoint resource types in great detail. It's about SharePoint 2007, but I think nothing has changed in this area (except for the fact that *14* is the new *12*).

> The provisioning resources are located
>   in the 12 hive in ..\12\Resources. In
>   WSS the default provisioning resource
>   file is **core.resx**. This file is used
>   in site definitions (one.xml) files,
>   features, list definitions etc.
>
> [...]
>
> **Nevertheless the provisioning resource
>   files are not accessible from the
>   ASP.NET web sites.** This is where the
>   run-time resources come to play. These
>   files are used in vanilla ASP.NET
>   sites and are located in the web
>   application folder under
>   ..\wss\VirtualDirectories[port]\App_GlobalResources.
>   They are compiled automatically by the
>   .Net framework in the Resources
>   namespace. These resources are
>   available in assemblies and directly
>   in ASPX pages. To access them from the
>   code use the strongly-typed notation
>   Resources.[file prefix].[resource
>   name]. In ASPX pages use the explicit
>   expression <%$ Resources:[filename
>   prefix,]resource-key %>. The default
>   WSS resource file in this category,
>   used by all WSS sites, is **wss.resx**.

Comment: Thanks for this. We want to use out of the box resource strings, but I had no idea that the 12/14 hive only comes into play at creation of the web application. What a mess. I guess it shows where localization ranks priority wise to the SharePoint team.

Comment: @Rich Bennema The resource files stored in the *[12/14 hive]\Resources* folder cannot be accessed directly, but you can use the `SPUtility.GetLocalizedString` method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getlocalizedstring.aspx). Example: `SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:" + key, "core", lcid)`